# Holomorphic line bundle on complex connected manifold

Tags: complex-analysis, differential-geometry, complex-geometry

In Huybrechts book there is an exercise 2.2.5 :

Let $X$ be a complex compact manifold and $L$ a holomorphic line bundle on $X$. Show that $L$ is trivial if and only if $L$ and its dual $L^*$ admit a non trivial global sections.

Huybrechts didn't mention that the manifold is connected. Is it possible to do the exercise without this condition? This is my solution:

Consider a global section $t$ of the dual bundle and $s$ is the section of $L$, considering local descriptions $L ↔ \{U_α, g_{α\beta}\}$, $L^{-1} ↔ \{U_α, g_{α\beta}^{-1}\}$, $s ↔ \{U_α, s_α\}$ and $t ↔ \{U_α, t_α\}$ he observes that on every $U_\alpha \cap U_\beta$ we have $s_\alpha t_\alpha = s_\beta t_\beta$, so we can glue these $s_\alpha t_\alpha$ in a "global" function $F: X \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$. By the maximum principle, since $X$ is compact, $F \equiv c \in \mathbb{C}$. (we shouldn't suppose $X$ is connected?).

Comment: Just work with each connected component and conclude that the restrictions of L are trivial. From this you get triviality of L.

Comment: But connected components are not closed in $X$. So I can't use my argument.

Comment: The connected components of $X$ are always both open and closed in $X$.

Comment: $X$ is connected, so we cannot find a subset of $X$ which is open and closed !

Comment: I thought you weren't assuming $X$ is connected.

Comment: If a topological space is a topological manifold then connected components are not only closed (they always are!) but are also open. Proving both claims is a very good exercise in general topology that you should do before you continue your study of complex manifolds.

Comment: @MoisheKohan but the sections might vanish on different components, while still being non-trivial (globally). Therefore, you cannot reduce to components.

Comment: @Ben: This is irrelevant. Just prove triviality of the bundle on each component. Then the bundle will be trivial overall.

Comment: No, if the sections are trivial on different components, the statement just fails. (You cannot restrict to a component when one of the sections is zero on that component.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a subtle point here. If $X=X_1\amalg X_2$ is a disjoint union of compact complex manifolds admitting non-trivial line bundles $L_1$ and $L_2$ with non-zero sections $s_i\in H^0(X_i,L_i)$, then $M=L_1\amalg L_2^\vee$ is a line bundle on $X$ with non-zero* sections $s_1\amalg 0\in H^0(X,M)$ and $0\amalg s_2\in H^0(X, M^\vee)$ (identifying $L_2=L_2^{\vee\vee}$ via the canonical isomorphism). However, $M$ is not trivial.

*) "non-zero" meaning "not totally zero". Note that these sections vanish on (different) components.

If, however, both sections are non-zero on each component, then the statement becomes true, e.g., by carrying out the argument on each component separately, as was suggested in the comments to the OP.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Nice example. If I understand, the statement is false, but if I suppose the sections are non-zero on each component, then $L$ is trivial. I think it's the same proof mentioned in my question.

Comment: Yes, exactly. Concerning your argument, the point is not just that the global holomorphic function obtained is (locally) constant, it's also that it is non-zero, I think.

Comment: Many Thanks. I write the solution here for the other members. If the function$F$  is zero on a open set $U_\alpha$, that mean $s_\alpha$ or $t_\alpha$ is vanish, then $s_{U_\alpha}$ or $t_{U_\alpha}$ is zero. And now we use the connectedness of $X$, we have $s=0$ or $t=0$. Contradiction. The $F\ne 0$, and in particular $s_\alpha$ don't have a zero for any $\alpha$, i.e, the section $s$ don't have any zero on $X$. Then $L$ is trivial .